# Nhibernate order of SQL statements when flushing session

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

According to NHibernate documentation, SQL statements are issued in the following order when a session is flushed:

- all entity insertions, in the same order the corresponding objects were saved using ISession.Save()
- all entity updates
- all collection deletions
- all collection element deletions, updates and insertions
- all collection insertions
- all entity deletions, in the same order the corresponding objects were deleted using ISession.Delete()

Why is it forced in this order and is there any way to change it so that the statements are executed in the same order that I give them?

Comment: I am intrigued by this. Why do you want a different order, what is it are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok without getting into too much detail, I have a many to many table (with a composite pk) that I'm trying to delete first and then reinsert when saving the parent; I've set inverse=true on the parent collection so I have to manage the saving myself, but because the inserts happen before the deletes I get a constraint violation if I need to resave an old many to many part. I've only been playing around with NH for a day or so, still trying to work out the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in that order because it's the safest.

And no, you can't change the order. But also, you never gave NHibernate any order: you just mark entities for persistence; NHibernate determines what to do automatically.

If you think you need more control over individual SQL operations, you can use `IStatelessSession` instead of a regular `ISession`. You lose all the stuff NH does automatically (lazy loading, caching, dirty-tracking), but you can (must) say explicitly when to `Insert`, `Delete` or `Update` a record.

Comment: It is probably the safest, but you need to remember about it every step of the way it and even a, normally simple, delete->insert becomes tricky. (For records with a unique property/column s.Delete;s.Save will not work).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the order NHibernate generates SQL in per the above, but you can chunk up the units of work.

eg:

```
using(var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var company = Session.QueryOver<Company>().First();
    var employee = new Employee{ ID = Guid.NewID() };
    company.Employees.Add(employee);
    Session.Flush();    

    var carSpace = new CarParkingSpace { EmployeeID = employee.ID };
    Session.Save(carSpace);

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

By adding the Session.Flush() - everything to that point will be pushed to the transaction. Without it, NHibernate would try to create a parking space allocated to a not yet existing employee.